# Python - if x not in any of a, b, c

Tags: python, if-statement

In a program I am writing at the moment I need to do the following:

```
if (x not in a) and (x not in b) and (x not in c):
```

which, of course, is very tedious, especially when a, b, and c all have much longer names.

Is there a built-in function that can do this:

```
if x is_in_one_of(a, b, c):
```

I know how I can do this with a function, and I am just wondering if there is a built-in way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would vote you keep it the way you have it as it is much more readable and obvious than any of the concise methods in the answers. Just break onto a new line before each 'and'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that as:

```
if all(x not in i for i in (a,b,c)):
```

The `all` above will only evaluate to `True` if x is not in any of a,b, or c

Or in other words:

```
if not any(x in i for i in (a,b,c)):
```

Comment: IMHO `not any(x in i for i in (a,b,c))` is more intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for built-in ways of doing it but as you have it is very readable, albeit tedious to  type. You could break onto a newline before each 'and'

For example (pep8 compliant)

```
if x not in a \
        and x not in b \
        and x not in c:
```

Alternatively, you could always use concatenation if appropriate

```
if x not in a + b + c:
```

Comment: you could use parentheses instead of backslashes. Leave operators (`and`) on the same line, see pep-8

Answer (score -1):

Put it in a list

```
val = [a, b, c, d, e]
if x not in val:
    do stuff
```

also this would work

```
if x not in [a, b, c]
```

Comment: might have misunderstood, is a,b,c also list themselves ?

Comment: Yes, they are also lists

Comment: This test is equivalent to `x != a and x != b and x != c` rather than `x not in a and x not in b and x not in c`.